# Populate array style form fields with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I would like to POST a form with attributes as described here (MVC friendly array): https://stackoverflow.com/a/5003686/1246219
The reason I want to POST a form rather than using ajax is that the result is a file for download, i.e.there is no other reason for using a form.

However I have a javascript array containing the values (integers) that I would like to submit. The only ways to achieve this that I can think of are either to loop through and create input elements for each entry, or I could just populate a single form field with a comma delimited string and parse it server side. Is there a better way?

UPDATE - 
If anyone is interested I have ended up with the loop approach, and happened to write it with d3 instead.

```
var selected = [1,2,3];
var selectionBinding = d3.select("#myForm").selectAll("input[name='myField']").data(selected);
selectionBinding.exit().remove();
selectionBinding.enter().append("input")
                .attr("type", "hidden")
                .attr("name", "myField")
                .attr("value", function (data) { return data });
$("#myForm").submit();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion would be to create a `regular Javascript Array` with data and have a form with `input type text`. When you submit the form set the value of the input text as `JSON.stringify(myArray)`

Comment: Thanks closure that is a good idea. In the end Ive actually gone the other way with a loop